# Debugging features on Safari to find out when elements added to page

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Is there a tool available on Safari to find out when new elements are being added to the page.  I have a page where there are invisible elements added at that cause the page to scroll.  The elements that I thought where the cause, don't seem to be.  I'd like to know if there is a way to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari's built-in debugging tools are limited to what Chrome and Firefox offers and as far as I know you cannot set a break point to detect when a node has been inserted.

If you really insist on using Safari to debug, you could use event listeners like below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
    console.log('This element was added to the page:', event.target);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This was quite helpful for dealing with a bug that only showed up in Safari. I ended up using a different [mutation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Web Inspector (or Chrome Developer Tools), right click on the BODY element (or a more specific one, where the elements actually get added) and in the context menu, choose "Break on subtree modifications". Your JS code will break whenever the selected element's subtree gets modified (elements added/removed).

Comment: While Chrome Developer Tools has this option, the Safari Developer tools do not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "mutation observers".